# How would I store these values into an object from a .txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm new to programming and I was wondering how I would store values into variables in a class using arrays if I'm getting the values from a .txt file. The values would be either strings or ints, how would you adjust to make this work? Here is the text from the txt. file.

```
Kobe Bryant

USA

4250000

25

21.03

NBA

Lebron James

USA

6450000

27

21.03

NBA
```

So I need to store each set of 6 values into 6 separate variables in a class using an array. The second index of the array will call the next 6 values.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Class which contains name, country, Salary, age etc.
2. Create a List of yourClass instances.
3. Read from file and store them in the list.

Comment: How would i create a list of yourClass instances, I'm fairly new to programming and i'm not sure how i would do that

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private int salary;
    private int age;
    private double someValue;
    private String league;

    public Person() { }
    public Person(String name, String country, int salary, int age, double someValue, String league) { //set them }
    //add setX and getX methods
```

}

In you main class:

```
  List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which contains all the necessary details you want to store in the array list. Then write the details on the text file and using the file concept read the data from the file and create an Array list  object to store the data into an array list.